# WPF import multiple txt files

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vbscript

I'm new to WPF. I have WPF application that allows user to export database as txt file. database has fixed number of columns but rows are not limited.
My problem is following:

1. I need to import multiple txt files and they need to be added one below another.
2. after all files are imported I need to make queries (sql) over imported data.

I have used this piece of code which imports one txt file (but it should more), but I can't make a search on data..

Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        'Create OpenFileDialog 
        Dim dlg As Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog = New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()

```
    ' Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"
    dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"

    ' Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
    If (dlg.ShowDialog() = True) Then

        '; Open document 
        Dim filename As String = dlg.FileName
        FileNameTextBox.Text = filename

        Dim paragraph As Paragraph = New Paragraph()
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename))
        Dim document As FlowDocument = New FlowDocument(paragraph)
        FlowDocReader.Document = document
    End If

End Sub
```

thx :)

Comment: You should try something and come back with specific questions when/if it doesn't work.

Comment: I have put on main window a button, txtbox and FlowDocument Reader. button has this code: `code` Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        'Create OpenFileDialog 
        Dim dlg As Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog = New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()

        ' Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"

        ' Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
        If (dlg.ShowDialog() = True) Then

            `code`

Comment: `code`  '; Open document 
            Dim filename As String = dlg.FileName
            FileNameTextBox.Text = filename

            Dim paragraph As Paragraph = New Paragraph()
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename))
            Dim document As FlowDocument = New FlowDocument(paragraph)
            FlowDocReader.Document = document
        End If

    End Sub  `code` it inserts one txt file. but I can't make a search on inserted data...

Comment: edit your original question with these code samples...